# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В советские времена вся энергетическая арматура производилась в четырех местах: в Чехове, Таганроге, Белгороде (,) и был большой завод в Темиртау.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фраза чисто разговорная, в письменном виде так, думаю,  нельзя. Если можно, то запятая ставится.

Comment: Спасибо! :)

Comment: Абсолютно верно! Предложение нужно перестроить! Ну если вы взялись на письме передать устную речь, то запятая нужна, она закрывает однородный ряд.

Comment: И открывает 2 часть ССП.